# Modx migration aliases update

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

I have a site migrated from modx evolution to revolution. Is there an easy way to rewrite modx resources' aliases (urls) preserving the hierarchy, for example:

```
About us (parent) 
client (child)
```

so the url would be: site.com/about-us/client

As I see, in modx evolution alias was taken from alias field, now in modx revolution it is in the uri field, I could copy it from alias to uri, but hierarchy will be broken, and all resources will have urls like: site.com/xxx

Answer (score 1):

You may have to manually edit the pages and make sure the alias are created.

Auto Generate Alias also needs to be yes.

Additionally, make sure you are actually using the Resource Field you are wanting to.

pagetitle, longtitle, menutitle are all options (as well as others), but if they are empty on the Resource page, they will be so on the web page presented to the visitor also.

Answer (score 0):

Just set system setting "use_alias_path" to Yes - http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/use_alias_path

Comment: I have it turned on, but on site all hrefs are empty

Comment: You enable frendly urls after adding all resources?